# What kind of kernel does MS Windows have?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

I saw a question on Linux Kernel. While reading that I had [this doubt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806585/why-linux-is-called-monolithic-kernel).

Comment: The discussion about various types of kernel usually comes from the point of view of having a prejudice and wanting to put a name to it. All major kernel implementations are modular, but massive. Windows is no more or less modular than Linux, OSX, Android or any other non-experimental or specialist OS.

Answer (score 10):

The Windows NT branch of windows has a Hybrid Kernel. It's neither a monolithic kernel where all services run in kernel mode or a Micro kernel where everything runs in user space. This provides a balance between the protection gained from a microkernel and the performance that can be seen in a monolithis kernel (as there are fewer user/kernel mode context switches).

As an example, device drivers and the Hardware Abstraction layer run in kernel node but the Workstation service runs in user mode. The wikipedia article on [Hybrid Kernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_kernel) has a good overview.

The [Windows Internals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901.aspx) book gives an explanation for the hybrid approach

> ... The Carnegie Mellon University Mach
>   operating  system, a contemporary
>   example of a microkernel architecture,
>   implements a minimal  kernel that
>   comprises thread scheduling, message
>   passing, virtual memory, and device 
>   drivers. Everything else, including
>   various APIs, ﬁle systems, and
>   networking, runs in  user mode.
>   However, commercial implementations of
>   the Mach microkernel operating system
>   typically run at least all ﬁle system,
>   networking, and memory management 
>   code in kernel mode. The reason is
>   simple: the pure microkernel design is
>   commercially  impractical because it’s
>   too inefﬁcient.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_7) it's a [Hybrid kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_kernel). Which may or may not be just marketing speak for about the same as a monolithic one. The graphic on the latter page does make some things clearer, though.

Most importantly, almost no program on Windows uses the kernel API directly. And the complete Windows API subsystem resides in user space which is a rather large part of the OS as we see it. And in more recent versions Microsoft began to pull more and more device drivers from kernel space into user space (which is especially a good idea with certain drivers, such as for video cards which are probably as complex as an operating system on their own).

Comment: Thanks..
And Wikipedia says the category, "Hybrid" is controversial due to the similarity to monolithic kernel.

Answer (score 5):

hyru hybrid kernel is the name of the Kernel that Windows systems after Windows 98, before that it was a GUI overlaid on DOS using a monolithic Kernel.