# modular kernel vs micro kernel / monolitic kernel

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel, microkernel

I am C programmer and new to the Linux kernel programming. I could find there are 3 type of kernel monolithic,micro and modular kernel.while googling i could find some website say linux is having monolithic kernel (in Stack overflow)  and some other says micro kernel and the rest say hybrid kernel. So i am totally confused while reading the modular concept which say new module for driver can be added without recompiling the kernel, which is against my assumption that Linux uses monolithic kernel. monolithic kernel runs in single **address space** and as a **single processes**    this is also bit confusing if so

Comment: It's a large, monolithic kernel. Compare it to [Plan 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plan_9_from_Bell_Labs) or [Mach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach_(kernel)) to get a better sense of the differences.

Answer (score 17):

Before you try to understand those differences, you have to understand other concepts first:

## 1. Modular programming.

Module is a functionally complete part of a program. Module usually has following properties:

1. Separation of *interface* and *implementation*.
2. *Initialization* and *deinitialization* routines. Both are optional. Deinitialization routine is likely to be missing in environment with GC (Garbage Collector).
3. Modules used by a program compose directed acyclic graph a.k.a. dependency graph (you might have heard about this - cyclic dependencies are not allowed, dependency is initialized before dependent module).

Modular programming is essential when building large systems. Every big kernel is a *modular kernel*, regardless of whether it is monolithic, hybrid or microkernel.

Sometimes modules can be loaded and unloaded dynamically. Dynamic modules are essential part of any *extensible system*. Those can be plugins or, if we talk about kernels, drivers that are developed and distributed separately from the kernel.

## 2. Safe and unsafe languages.

Safe languages very strictly define what can happen in a program. Most importantly they have no concept of *malformed* program (or *meaningless* program). Every program is valid and its execution always follows language specification. Whether program does what programmer expects it to do or not, is irrelevant in this context.

Common traits of safe languages:

1. They use garbage collection.
2. They have no pointer arithmetics. That means that writing or reading to an arbitrary address is not allowed.
3. They prevent out of range array access (if there is such concept). Exceptions or similar mechanisms can be used to signal and recover from such failures.
4. References (or pointers) have only two possible states: null reference and reference to a valid object. This is guaranteed by garbage collector. In fact, GC is the key component here. Some languages go even further and do no allow null references at all.
5. Every object (memory chunk in use) has type information assigned to it, object can only be accessed through a reference of appropriate type e.g. you cannot access array of integers through reference to a string.

You can add more entries to this list, but basic idea is to guarantee that program can only access valid memory regions using valid operations. Keep in mind that some unsafe languages can share some or even all of those traits.

Examples of safe languages: Python, Java, safe subset of C#.

Unsafe languages define what can and cannot be done in a program, but there is usually little to nothing to stop programmer from doing the wrong thing. Program that violates those rules is called a *malformed program*. From language point of view such program is meaningless and language does not even try to define its behavior, as it is usually near to impossible to do. In terms of C such program's behavior is *undefined*.

Examples of unsafe languages: Assembler, C, C++, Pascal.

## 3. Hardware is unsafe and thus has to be programmed using unsafe language.

Most hardware does nothing to provide you with a safe environment. There were some processors that used to attach type information to every memory cell (see [tagged architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_architecture)), but modern ones do not do this as it complicates hardware, making it slower, more expensive and less generic.

Still, some features are provided to make it possible to implement safe environments within unsafe environment of hardware, such as memory protection, separate address spaces and separation of execution modes on *user mode* and *kernel mode* (a.k.a. *supervisor mode*).

Kernel is what runs on bare metal and thus much of it has to be written in unsafe languages like C and Assembly. Another reason is performance - safe environments imply huge overhead.

## Microkernel and Monolithic kernel

Monolithic kernel and its modules run in a single shared address space. And since everything is usually written in an unsafe language, it is possible for any part of the kernel to access (and damage) memory that belongs to another part of the kernel due to bugs in code. Unsafe nature of this environment makes it impossible to detect or recover from those failures and most importantly predict kernel behavior after such failures.

Microkernel is an attempt to overcome those limitation by moving various parts of the kernel to a separate address spaces, effectively isolating them from each other, but providing safe way to communicate with each other (usually through message passing). Such separation creates safe environment composed from multiple unsafe processes, allowing kernel to recover from failure of some of its subsystems.

At the same time monolithic kernel can be able to run parts of it in a separate address space ([FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)), while nothing stops microkernel from being able to support modules that share address space with the main part of the kernel.

If most of the kernel runs in a single address space, it is considered to be a monolithic kernel. If most of it runs in separate address spaces, such kernel is considered to be a microkernel. If kernel is somewhere inbetween and actively uses both approaches, you have a *hybrid kernel*.

## Hybrid kernel

Concept of hybrid kernel implies combining best of both worlds and was invented by Microsoft to boost sales of Windows NT in 90s. Joke! But this is almost true. Every important part of Windows NT runs in a shared address space, so it is another example of monolithic design.

Many people seem to use this term when describing monolithic kernel that is able to dynamically load modules. This is because in the past monolithic kernels didn't support dynamic module loading and had to be recompiled every time module is added to the kernel. Microkernels are not about dynamic module loading, but about reliability of the kernel, about its ability to recover from failues of its subsystems.

---

## The answer: Linux is a monolithic kernel.

---

Monolithic kernel *can* be modular and *can* dynamically load modules. Microkernel, on the other hand, *has* to be modular and *has* to be able to dynamically load modules - the whole idea is about running them in a separate address space.

---

Microkernel is not the only way of overcoming unsafe nature of monolithic kernel. Another way is to write monolithic kernel in a safe language. One problem with such approach is that safe environment should be either provided by hardware (and will be very limited) or should be implemented in software using unsafe languages. Implementation of such environment will be extremely complex and will most likely have many bugs (think of all bugs found in JVM).

Example of this would be experimental OS [Singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singularity_(operating_system)).

Answer (score 0):

Well, considering that I may have a quiz on this tomorrow, I should be able to help you out. However, I am still learning, and while my post may have some technical mistakes, it should be conceptually sound

Basically, as you may understand, there are different type of kernels for an OS.

Monolithic kernels have all their system functionalities and services together in one single giant program, occupying a single address space.
Microkernels on the other hand, have the bare minimum system programs and services on the microkernel. Most of the services that were previously considered as a part of the kernel (during the monolithic kernel version) such as process scheduler, etc. are now in the user space, and are termed as servers. these servers communicate with each other through the micro-kernel, using the inter-process communication, a form of communication that is laid down by the microkernel.
The modular approach builds on this, by making these "servers" dynamically loadable. Thus, one can have a particular "server" (in this type of kernel, called a module) dynamically loaded, without the kernel requiring to re-compile itself.

Linux Kernel is a monolithic kernel, but most flavours of Linux such as Ubuntu, Solaris, use a hybrid kernel, i.e. a mix of the monolithic and modular kernel approach. This is quite common, has different kernel structure has different pros and cons, and a hybrid structure is required to strike a balance

Comment: Yes i got some break through from the above explanation. As you said monolithic kernel occupy a single address space so if a user process is running , will it share the monolithic adress space or , seperate adress space for that user process,entirely different from monolithic single address space

Comment: As far as I understand, the user address space will be the same for all cases. One major reason for this is that a process may use one module once and another module at a different time. The modules will be located at different address spaces. Also, considering that Linux OS (eg. Ubuntu) uses hybrid modular monolithic kernels (where the kernel is one big thing with modules that can be loaded to the kernel), having different address spaces don't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

See [this prior StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806585/why-is-linux-called-a-monolithic-kernel) for some information about your question. Briefly, it sounds like you're wondering...

> ... reading the modular concept which say new module for driver can be added without recompiling the kernel, which is against my assumption that Linux uses monolithic kernel. monolithic kernel runs in single address space and as a single process ...

These two concepts ("modular kernel" and "single address space") are not actually contradictory. You can build a new kernel module without recompiling the entire Linux kernel. When you load this new kernel module, it will actually be loaded into the **same address space** as the running kernel itself. From the link above...

> Do not confuse the term modular kernel to be anything but monolithic. Some monolithic kernels can be compiled to be modular (e.g Linux), what matters is that the module is inserted to and runs from the same space that handles core functionality (kernel space).

As you have found, there are several ways to classify kernels and the different types are not necessarily mutually exclusive.